# Unable to set focus to the next text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three text boxes all with the class "initialbox".

The max length for each box is 1 character. When a box has been filled with one character, the next box should be set as focus. (The exact same way that using the TAB key would work).

I added the `alert()` in order to check that the event if firing, and it is, but the `$(this).next('.initialbox').focus()` doesn't set the focus to the next tab. I have tried also using `$(this).next.focus()`.

Many thanks.

HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:33.3%">
            <input type="text" class="initialbox" maxlength="1" size="1" id="firstinitial" />
        </td>
        <td style="width:33.3%">
            <input type="text" class="initialbox" maxlength="1" size="1" id="secondinitial" />
        </td>
        <td style="width:33.3%">
            <input type="text" class="initialbox" maxlength="1" size="1" id="thirdinitial" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:33.3%">1st Initial</td>
        <td style="width:33.3%">2nd Initial</td>
        <td style="width:33.3%">3rd Initial</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".initialbox").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == 1) {
        alert();
        $(this).next('.initialbox').focus();
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9y51pds/1/

Comment: Your HTML example here is not the same as in your fiddle. With the markup in your question your code should work ..

Comment: Your question is misleading. It's usually good practice to be consistent when posting your code and markup. One can understand what you were attempting to do, but if you change your markup, then the corresponding jQuery would change.

Comment: Sorry, Wanted to keep the code in the question simple and left it out as I didn't think the table was the cause of the issue. Two weeks with 14 hour days is getting to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use `.next()` with your markup, because your `.initialbox` input elements aren't siblings.

You need to traverse to the parent (`closest()`) `<td>`, along to it's neighbour `<td>` and then find the `.initialbox` within:

```
$(".initialbox").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == 1) {
        alert();
        $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('.initialbox').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Working fine. I had assumed it would just find the next textbox with the class. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead (for the code in your fiddle):

```
$(".initialbox").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == 1) {
        $(this).parent('td').next('td').find('.initialbox').focus();
    }
});
```

[See it work here](http://jsfiddle.net/v9y51pds/3/)

The problem was `$(this).next()` is looking at siblings, not the entire dom. So you need to traverse the dom to find the element you want to focus next.

<sub>(edited to add 'td' to the `.parent()` and `.next()` bits to make it clearer what's going on)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to traversing up and down the DOM is to grab the **[`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)** of the input within the `$('.initialbox')` collection.

You can then go directly to the next input like this:

```
$('.initialbox').keyup(function() {
  var idx= $('.initialbox').index(this);
  if(this.value.length == 1) {
    $('.initialbox').eq(idx+1).focus();
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ptgn4jt8/)